# Mdl: Material Icon in input field

Tags: html, css, material-design, elm

I am looking into a way to get the following (taken from the material website):

[image: Hide password example]

I have managed to do get an icon in an input field with Bootstrap using input-group. But I cannot find a good and clear way on how to do this with mdl.

I am using elm but a html/css solution is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with some css stuff.

```
passwordIconStyle : Attribute Msg
passwordIconStyle =
    style
        [ ("position", "absolute")
        , ("top", "18px")
        , ("right", "5px")
        , ("cursor", "pointer")
        ]

passwordField : Model -> Html Msg
passwordField model =
    div [ style [ ("position", "relative") ] ]
        [ Textfield.render Mdl [1] model.mdl
            [ Textfield.label "Password"
            , Textfield.floatingLabel
            , Textfield.password
            , Textfield.value model.password
            , Textfield.error model.passwordError
                |> Options.when (not <| isEmpty model.passwordError)
            , Options.onInput UpdatePassword
            , Options.css "padding-right" "40px"
            ]
            []
        , i [ passwordIconStyle ]
            [
                visibility Color.gray 25
            ]
        ]
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've done an [this](https://embed.ellie-app.com/yCFWg8nhH2a1/1) small example. I hope it can help you.

```
import Material as Mdl
import Material.Textfield as Textfield
import Html exposing (..)


type alias Model =
    { mdl :
        Mdl.Model
    }


model : Model
model =
    { mdl =
        Mdl.model
        -- Boilerplate: model store for any and all Mdl components you use.
    }


type Msg
    = Mdl (Mdl.Msg Msg)


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        -- Boilerplate: Mdl action handler.
        Mdl msg_ ->
            Mdl.update Mdl msg_ model


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ Textfield.render Mdl
            [ 2 ]
            model.mdl
            [ Textfield.label "Floating label"
            , Textfield.floatingLabel
            , Textfield.text_
            ]
            []
        , Textfield.render Mdl
            [ 5 ]
            model.mdl
            [ Textfield.label "Enter password"
            , Textfield.floatingLabel
            , Textfield.password
            ]
            []
        ]


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    Html.program
        { view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        , init = ( model, Cmd.none )
        }
```

Remember that you have to add to your `index.html` links to the css of `mdl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am looking specifically on how to get the visibility icon in the password field :)

Comment: According to the material design lite, and the docs of `elm-mdl` I think you just can have icon on the expandable textfield, and I think that is not what you are looking for. The screenshot you gave us is from the material design website, but not from material design lite...

Comment: I solved it using some css. Im not happy with the input fields line stopping for the icon, but otherwise if the password was too long, it could go under the icon.